# Firebase onDataChange bug with android 7?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying my app with android 7.0 API 24 and android 6.01 API 23 and the one with API 24 is giving me hell..

I have this code:

```
            DatabaseReference online = mPostReference.child("online").child(msg.friend_id);
            online.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Online post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Online.class);
                    if ( viewHolder.getDiff(post.timestamp) < 1){
                        System.out.println("True: " + msg.friend_id + viewHolder.getDiff(post.timestamp));
                        viewHolder.setOnline("visible");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("False: " + viewHolder.getDiff(post.timestamp));
                        viewHolder.setOnline("gone");
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
                }
            });
```

**Situation:**
When user B logs in the data timestamp is updated and next to the profile pic for user A online bubble appears. 
If user B presses back button, the timestamp is updated with the value of +5 min which makes onDataChange to get the second value which is in else statement and the online bubble will dissapear instantly.

The problem I am having is that in API 23 works fine..I log in, it shows the online bubble, I press back button, app closes, firebase db is updated and the bubble disapears as the values changed and onDataChange fires up this change.

But on API 25 it doesnt work this way. If user logs in, sometimes online bubble appears on all of the users inside viewHolder sometimes just for the correct one. (if appears for all of the users, I have to refresh the activity and it shows just for the 1) If user presses back button and exits the app, the firebase db will be updated but the state of online bubble will not change until I exit my app or go to a different activity to force check onDataChange on return.

Is this the bug or I am missing something here???

Comment: Are you notifying the adapter when changing the viewholder? Also you should store the value event listener you add and stop listening to it when the activity is detroyed.

Comment: I realised recently that i have to stop the listener as multiple listeners are created once app reopens. And yes, I do notify the adapter. But this still makes no sence as the API23 behaves differently than API 24 for some reason with the same code,..